# Coulomb's law in medium

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

As we know that when we replace vacuum by some medium between two point electric charges then the force between them becomes 1/K times the initial value, where K is the dielectric constant of medium. I want to know that if we cut out some portion of the medium from in between, how does the force will change then?

Comment: I guess you are talking about a dielectric medium. If you want to cut out a slab in a plane perpendicular to the line connecting the two charges, you're going to have to solve some boundary value problems.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The answer will depend on the hole in the medium.